# Spring boot micro service architecture find number of instances of service

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka, netflix-ribbon

I am trying to set up micro service architecture using `spring boot`. I have created it by separating the components and using techniques like `ribbon`, `eureka naming server`, `zuul API` etc.

`service1` reading inputs from a db and calling `service2` through ribbon, eureka and zuul.

```
List<Object> inputs= ...
for(Object input: inputs){
    service2Proxy.process(input); // calling service 2
}
```

Is it possible to call the `service2` based on the number of available instance of `service2` ?
ie, If there are 3 instance of `service2` is available at a time, I need to call only 3 requests to `service2` at a time.

What is the solution for this problem?

Comment: Any specific reason why you want to do that, as the Ribbon client side load balancer will keep on distributing the call with round robin policy.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `LoadBalancerClient` directly (by autowiring) and then use `LoadBalancerClient.choose(serviceId)`, then you can get hold of the `ServiceInstance` it returns. This contains the uri of the service. So after each invocation store this uri in a set of uri's and before making another call check if you have already used the server instance already.If all servers have been exhausted wait for further inputs. When you are ready to process again, clear the set and repeat.  As explained in the docs [here](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html), the code would be somewhat like this

```
@Autowired
    private LoadBalancerClient loadBalancer;

    public void doStuff() {
        ServiceInstance instance = loadBalancer.choose("stores");
        URI serverUri = instance.getUri();
     // use you logic here
        URI storesUri = URI.create(String.format("http://%s:%s", instance.getHost(), instance.getPort()));

    }
```